# Shutting down spring application context

Tags: java, spring

I have a web application which creates 2 spring application contexts.

The first is the parent or root context and the second is a child declared like so:

```
ApplicationContext parent = new GenericApplicationContext();
parent.registerShutdownHook();
parent.refresh();

ApplicationContext child = new GenericApplicationContext();
child.setParent(parent);
```

My question is: Do I need to call registerShutdownHook() on the child context aswell?

Thanks,

For your help.

Comment: Why are you constructing an `ApplicationContext` yourself, why aren't you spring handle this (with a `ContextLoaderListener`)? To answer your question if you want you indeed need to call `registerShutdownHook()` again as it only applies to the context at hand.

Comment: The application is perhaps less traditional and starts a parent application context from main which spawns an embedded jetty server to launch the application.

Thanks for your response - good to get this clarified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must register a shut-down hook for each application context you create. This will ensure if the JVM is shut-down abruptly your beans will be disposed of cleanly.